# How can I make a dynamically generated tablelayout scrollable?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have 3 fragments inside an Activity and in two of the fragments I have a hardcoded `TableLayout` inside a `ConstraintLayout`, the headers and rows of the tables are dynamically generated with information from a MySQL server. Given its dynamic nature, the table is able to overflow the page and I want it to be scrollable.

There are already multiple questions on StackOverflow where people have wanted a scrollable table, but in the questions, the tables and their data are hardcoded (don't know if that is relevant or not). I have tried the solutions proposed in those questions but they don't work on my table. The solutions are generally to either wrap the `TableLayout` in a `ScrollView` or to use `android:isScrollContainer="1"` neither of which have worked for me.

`TableLayout` inside `ScrollView`. The `ScrollView` is there for testing, normally it is just the `TableLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewProductLocFragment">
    <!-- Rest of the fragment -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menuBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menuBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code that fills the table.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_product_main, container, false);
    initializeTableLayout(view);
    fillTable(((ViewProductActivity)getActivity()).pallets);

    return view;
}

private void fillTable(PalletsResult pallets)
{
    Integer count = 0;
    for(Pallet pallet : pallets.getPallets()) {

        String barcode = pallet.getBarcode();
        String location = pallet.getCode();
        Integer quantity = pallet.getQuantity();

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGrey));
        }
        tableRow.setId(View.generateViewId());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        TextView labelBarcode = new TextView(getContext());
        labelBarcode.setId(View.generateViewId());
        labelBarcode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        labelBarcode.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.standardTextColor));
        labelBarcode.setTextSize(18);
        labelBarcode.setText(barcode);
        tableRow.addView(labelBarcode);

        TextView labelLocation = new TextView(getContext());
        labelLocation.setId(View.generateViewId());
        labelLocation.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        labelLocation.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.standardTextColor));
        labelLocation.setTextSize(18);
        labelLocation.setText(location);
        tableRow.addView(labelLocation);

        TextView labelQuantity = new TextView(getContext());
        labelQuantity.setId(View.generateViewId());
        labelQuantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        labelQuantity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.standardTextColor));
        labelQuantity.setTextSize(18);
        labelQuantity.setText(quantity.toString());
        tableRow.addView(labelQuantity);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        count++;
    }
}

private void initializeTableLayout(View view)
{
    tableLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(getContext());
    tr_head.setId(View.generateViewId());
    tr_head.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGrey));
    tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));

    TextView label_barcode = new TextView(getContext());
    label_barcode.setId(View.generateViewId());
    label_barcode.setText("BARCODE");
    label_barcode.setTextSize(20);
    label_barcode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label_barcode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tr_head.addView(label_barcode);// add the column to the table row here

    TextView label_location = new TextView(getContext());
    label_location.setId(View.generateViewId());// define id that must be 
unique
    label_location.setText("LOCATION"); // set the text for the header
    label_location.setTextSize(20);
    label_location.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
    label_location.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tr_head.addView(label_location); // add the column to the table row here

    TextView label_quantity = new TextView(getContext());
    label_quantity.setId(View.generateViewId());// define id that must be 
unique
    label_quantity.setText("QTY"); // set the text for the header
    label_quantity.setTextSize(20);
    label_quantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
    label_quantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tr_head.addView(label_quantity); // add the column to the table row here

    tableLayout.setScrollContainer(true);
    tableLayout.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

This creates a table that runs off the end of the page and that can't be scrolled.

There is a fair bit of other code that I didn't post in regards to the Activity containing the fragments and what not. Let me know if you want any of that.

Thanks for any help.

**Update:** I implemented a similar table elsewhere in my app and it worked just fine with the code posted in my examples. This means that the problem I am having is realted to the table being in a fragment and not an activity. I will post some of my fragment code later.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried implementing your code over an Activity. I am posting my Activity and XML code for your reference, can you see what you are missing in your complete code so that this can be helpful.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TableLayout tableLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeTableLayout();

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    fillTable();
}

private void fillTable() {
    Integer count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        String barcode = "#0000000000";
        String location = "Location";
        Integer quantity = 1;

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
        }
        tableRow.setId(View.generateViewId());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        TextView labelBarcode = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        labelBarcode.setId(View.generateViewId());
        labelBarcode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        labelBarcode.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        labelBarcode.setTextSize(18);
        labelBarcode.setText(barcode);
        tableRow.addView(labelBarcode);

        TextView labelLocation = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        labelLocation.setId(View.generateViewId());
        labelLocation.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        labelLocation.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        labelLocation.setTextSize(18);
        labelLocation.setText(location);
        tableRow.addView(labelLocation);

        TextView labelQuantity = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        labelQuantity.setId(View.generateViewId());
        labelQuantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        labelQuantity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        labelQuantity.setTextSize(18);
        labelQuantity.setText(quantity.toString());
        tableRow.addView(labelQuantity);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        count++;
    }
}

private void initializeTableLayout() {
    tableLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
    tr_head.setId(View.generateViewId());
    tr_head.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
    tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView label_barcode = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    label_barcode.setId(View.generateViewId());
    label_barcode.setText("BARCODE");
    label_barcode.setTextSize(20);
    label_barcode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label_barcode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tr_head.addView(label_barcode);// add the column to the table row here

    TextView label_location = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    label_location.setId(View.generateViewId());// define id that must be         unique
    label_location.setText("LOCATION"); // set the text for the header
    label_location.setTextSize(20);
    label_location.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
    label_location.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tr_head.addView(label_location); // add the column to the table row here

    TextView label_quantity = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    label_quantity.setId(View.generateViewId());// define id that must be         unique
    label_quantity.setText("QTY"); // set the text for the header
    label_quantity.setTextSize(20);
    label_quantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
    label_quantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tr_head.addView(label_quantity); // add the column to the table row here

    tableLayout.setScrollContainer(true);
    tableLayout.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have manually added 100 dummy rows to test its scroll behaviour and would like to inform you that it is exactly working as it should. There could be a problem in your Activity or Fragment parent code which is preventing the table from scrolling.

Comment: Do you think it could have something to do with mine being a fragment and yours being an activity?

Comment: There can be an error. you can try posting your full code, or may a Git link if you want the community to look into it in detail.

Comment: I put your code into a brand new app for testing and it worked. Then I put that code into my fragment and it didn't work so I guess something else is the problem. If you wouldn't mind taking a quick look at my GitHub I would really appreciate it. Its a private repo so just message me your email and I'll add you.

Comment: Couldn't find a github account associated with that email address.

Comment: @Zac Here is the link to my GitHub profile
https://github.com/atishagrawal

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TableView library** to make your **Table scrollable** with dynamic data. The link is given below:-
https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like the look of this. If all else fails I'll start learning it.